# Left outer join with two tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Below sample tables i have.

Event table :-

```
id    eventName        modelId     sheetId

1     Input edit        1           2
2     Formula edit      2           1
3     Delete model      null        3
4     Delete sheet      3           null
```

Model table :-

```
id     modelName
1       test1
2       test2
3       test3
```

Sheet table :-

```
id      sheetName
1       testSheet1
2       testSheet2
3       testSheet3
```

Now my requirement is always i need all the records from event table ,  i need (all columns of event table + modelName and sheetName).

Below query i have written but this query not giving expected output although i know i need to use left outer join but am not able to do that :-

```
select
  e.id,e.eventName,e.modelId,e.sheetId,m.modelName,s.sheetName 
from
  Event e,
  Model m,
  Sheet s 
where e.modelId=m.id and e.sheetId=s.id;
```

**Expected Output** :-

```
id    eventName        modelId     sheetId    modelName    sheetName

1     Input edit        1           2          test1       testSheet2
2     Formula edit      2           1          test2       testSheet1
3     Delete model      null        3          null        testSheet3
4     Delete sheet      3           null       test3        null
```

Answer (score 0):

It's should be very basic query:

```
select
  e.id,e.eventName,e.modelId,e.sheetId,m.modelName,s.sheetName 
from
  Event e
left join 
  Model m on m e.modelId=m.id
left join
  Sheet s on e.sheetId=s.id;
```